# sapui5 TreeTable update binding

Tags: sapui5, treetable

I have a SAPUI5 application with an input field for a Period (Calendaryear / Month) and a TreeTable. Initialy the data for the current month is displayed.

This part of the application works fine.

When a new Period is selected the oData service is called and the tree table gets updated. But only the rows that were initialy visible get updated. No new rows are displayed.
There is an attachRequestCompleted function and I can see that all the new data is delivered from the oData Service.

How can the sapui5 TreeTable get completely updated/refreshed with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.model.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent){
    var oModel = oEvent.getSource();
    oModel.refresh();
});
```

[Refresh the model](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel/methods/refresh). This will check all bindings for updated data and update the controls if data has been changed.